# conflicting timein and timeout in scheduling system using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

How can I conflict timein and timeout with this code in my button save?

Sample is there is data store in ms access like `7:00-8:00` then I will save another one like `7:30-8:30` it must be conflict but in my program it will be save. Please I need help.

```
Dim scmd As New OledbCommand
with scmd 
    .connection = cn
    .commandtext = "select * from deptsched where.        [dtimein] <= #" & combo1.text & "# and [dtimeout]  >= #" &     combo2.text "# "
end with

Dim srdr As OleDbDataReader
srdr = scmd.ExecuteReader
If srdr.HasRows Then
msg("conflict")
exit sub

end if

with cmds
.connection = cn
.commandtext = insert into deptsched values('"& c1.text.   &"', '"& c2.text &"')"
.executenonquery()
end with


 msg(" save")
```

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56487148/good-day-to-all-my-problem-here-is-how-can-i-conflict-the-time-in-and-time-out).  It seems that both of these questions have the same query.

Comment: hi mary i run the code i did save lik 7:00-8:00 and its save and then i try saving other one like 7:30-8:30 its saving no conflict message i want that time yo be conflicted. please help thank you

Answer (score 0):

Truthfully, your Select statement doesn't make much sense to me but here is the code you can use to execute your sql statements. At the very least, this will give you a pattern to follow. You will have to check datatypes in the database and adjust the code accordingly.

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim RecordCount As Integer
    'Keep your data objects local so you can be sure they are closed and disposed.
    ' A Using...End Using block ensures this even if there is an error
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection("Your Connection String")
        'Pass the command text and the connection directly to the constructor of the command
        'Always use Parameters to avoid Sql injection
        'If all you need is a count of records then ask for Count no all the data
        Using scmd As New OleDbCommand("Select Count(*) From deptsched where [dtimein] <= @TimeIn And  [dtimeout]  >= @TimeOut;", cn) ' #" & combo1.text & "# and#" & combo2.text "# ")
            scmd.Parameters.Add("@TimeIn", OleDbType.Date).Value = CDate(combo1.Text)
            scmd.Parameters.Add("@TimeOut", OleDbType.Date).Value = CDate(combo2.Text)
            cn.Open()
            RecordCount = CInt(scmd.ExecuteScalar)
        End Using
    End Using
    If RecordCount > 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("conflict")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection("Your Connection String")
        Using cmds As New OleDbCommand("insert into deptsched values(@Field1, @Field2);", cn)
            cmds.Parameters.Add("@Field1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = c1.text
            cmds.Parameters.Add("@Field2", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = c2.text
            cn.Open()
            cmds.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using
    MessageBox.Show("Save")
End Sub
```